# illustrator: pathfinder minus front, cut-out is crude, not precise enough

Tags: adobe-illustrator, cs5, pathfinder

CS5.

Trying to cut out text from a shape behind it. I select the text, then Object > Expand..., then select it along with the rectangle shape behind it and do Pathfinder > Minus front. The cut-out shape comes looking wrong.

[image: Before]

[image: After]

In Pathfinder Options, I have the precision set to 0.001 pt (although it doesn't seem to change anything), the other options don't make a difference either. I've only had this problem with this particular rounded typeface. Any ideas how I can get it to cut directly along the outlined path?

Comment: Are you working at a very small size?

Comment: I considered this would be the case and scaled everything up 1000% with the same issue. But I'm not sure scale really matters regardless, it's all vectors, no raster..

Comment: Hinting can play a large part of type being outlined. If you outlined type when it is like 6pts or smaller, the hinting may be causing the Patherfinder hiccup. Just a thought. I've never encountered what you're displaying.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue was being caused by the rounded corners effect applied to the shape being cut. Moral of the story: rounded corners must be done manually if you don't want to alter the shape of the negative space within the shape as well.

Comment: If this solved your issue, you should mark your own answer as correct.